# html2pdf - Output('example.pdf','D'); error

Tags: pdf, output, html2pdf

I have managed to get a PDF of my HTML to display exactly as required in the browser, but can't get it to download, using

```
$html2pdf->Output('example.pdf','D');
```

It produces

```
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration
and was unable to complete your request.
```

All the other output commands work fine.

Can someone help please.

Answer (score 3):

OK, I don't seem to be able to find the answer to this, so I am now using a workaround and thought I should share it with others that are having the same problem.

I save the PDF file using;

```
$html2pdf->Output($filename, 'F');
```

Then offer it for download with;

```
Header("Content-type: application/pdf"); 
Header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename"); 
readfile("$filename");
```

Then delete the file  with;

```
unlink($filename);
```

This is working perfectly in Chrome. Not tested with other browsers